# htaccess rewrite %3F and %3D to ? and =

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm wanna rewrite all incoming URLs who at end have `%3Ffull%3D1` to `?full=1`

I'm try this in htaccess but not work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)%3F(.+)%3D(.+)$ $1?$2=$3 [R=301]
```

here is full .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)%3F(.+)%3D(.+)$ $1?$2=$3 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented the following .htaccess code to accomplish this - I've modified it to fit your scenario of using the "full" parameter.

```
# replace %3F with ? and %3D with =
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\%]+)\%3[Ff]full\%3[dD]([^\ ]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule \.*$ http://www.mywebsite.com/%1?full=%2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `L` flag in the rule that handles the query string:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)%3F(.+)%3D(.+)$ $1?$2=$3 [L,R=301]
```

otherwise, the rewritten URI could end up getting handled by the last rule (`RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`) and yet *still* get redirected because the URI was flagged for a 301. Also, if the original URL that you are trying to redirect contains `%3Ffull%3D1` **in the query string itself**, then your rule isn't going to match that, you'd need something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)%3Ffull%3D1(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1&full=%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: not work. or Im wrong. I wanna when someone click on link ie" www.mysite.com/some-perma-link%3Ffull3D1 browser redirect him to www.mysite.com/some-perma-link?full=1